# Stripe - Error: Cannot find symbol class Stripe

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, stripe-payments

I am importing a project from an old repo getting ready to publish to live. After I imported the app and have run `Sync project with Gradle files`. I get the following errors after I try to run the app on a device.

> Error:(38, 18) error: cannot find symbol class Stripe

followed by several

> Error:(6, 28) error: package com.stripe.exception does not exist

Here is my **build.gradle**

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.business.us.app'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        signingConfigVtraining {
            keyAlias 'Alias'
            keyPassword 'thepassword'
            storeFile file('../keystore/keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'storepassword'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.alihafizji.creditcardedittext:library:+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.sromku:simple-fb:4.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
    compile 'com.auron:permission-manage:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:0.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    compile project(':dateTimePicker')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts would be helpfull, Thank you!

Comment: use it... compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.0.3'

Comment: Same errors `Error:(38, 18) error: cannot find symbol class Stripe`

Comment: Can you try a clean build? I tried adding the library by myself and it worked and also I used your gradle file as is and it works fine for me.

Comment: @ArunShankar I created a new project with just an empty view and added the Gradle file, but it's having a hard time building. I get this error `Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :dateTimePicker.` after adding `include ':app', ':dateTimePicker'` to **settings.gradle**

Comment: @ArunShankar Also did you try to `import com.stripe.Stripe` in your **MainActivity.java** file?

Comment: The exposed package is com.stripe.android and I was able to .            import com.stripe.android.exception.APIConnectionException;

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "exposed package".. You mean what is supposed to be inside of my dependencies? `compile 'com.stripe.android'` doesn't work

Comment: I have come to understand what you are saying... Now I am having problems with `import com.stripe.android.model.Account` apparently this does not exist.